# Upload file with ajax then list them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

As I’m wrot in the title my aim is to upload a file via a form by AJAX and return the elements uploaded in a div.

**This is form HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-add">
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

**This is the traitement that I used in PHP to make the AJAX request**

```
if (isAjax()){
    $dir_ext_img = 'img/type_files';
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM upload WHERE idU= ? ORDER BY idF DESC');
    $req->execute([$idU]);
    $file_being_up = $req->fetch();
    ?>
       <div class="element_upload <?= $file_being_up->idF; ?>">
            <img src="<?= $dir_ext_img .'/'. $file_being_up->extension; ?>.svg">
            <a href="<?=$file_being_up->dir; ?>" class='name_file' target='_blank'><?= $file_being_up->nameF.'.'.$file_being_up->extension ; ?></a>
            <a href="delete.php?idF=<?= $file_being_up->idF; ?>" class='delete'>Supprimer</a>
      </div>
   <?php
} else{
      header('Location: account.php');
}
```

**This is the function isAjax code:**

```
function isAjax(){
   return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTES_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTES_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
 }
```

**This is my script JS in jQuery:**

```
$('#form-add').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData($form[0]) : null;
        var data = (formdata !== null) ? formdata : $form.serialize();
        var url = $form.attr('action');
        $form.find('button').text('Chargement...');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false, 
        data: data })
        .done(function(data, text, jqxhr){
            $('.container').prepend(jqxhr.responseText);
            $form.find('button').text('Envoyer');

         });
});
```

The probleme is that I don’t have in return the response of the div that I’ve create in the script PHP, however I receive a full page with the new div inside. 
Whereas I want only the previous div create in PHP to put it on the page where I want.
 Is anybody know what can I do to have juste a new div with the file uploaded ?

Comment: Erfff sorry I fix the problem it was here:
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTES_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTES_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';

Comment: it's not : HTTP_X_REQUESTES_WITH

Comment: But it's HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'    ===> with the lettre 'D'  ^_^